# Lebnitz rule,covariant derivation

Tags: derivatives, manifolds, smooth-manifolds, connections

How the **Leibnitz rule**

$\nabla_X f(Y)=Xf(Y)+f\nabla_X Y$

implies

$\nabla_{\dot{c}}\dot{c}=\lambda \dot{c}$

for some real number $\lambda$ and diffeomorphism $\phi:I_1\to I$?

Here $\nabla_{\dot{c}}{\dot{c}}=0$ for the reparametrized $c$ and $c\circ\phi:I\to M$ is a geodetic.
Also $\nabla$ is a linear connection on the manifold $M$.

See the first paragraph [HERE](http://www.math.uni-hamburg.de/home/belgun/Weyl-proj.pdf).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume that $\alpha(t)$ is a geodesic. Then $$\nabla_\dot{\alpha}\dot{\alpha}=0.$$ For a reparametrization $\lambda$, i.e., $t=\lambda(s)$ and $\alpha(t)=\alpha(\lambda(s))$ we have

$$\frac{d\alpha}{ds}=\frac{d\alpha}{dt}\times \frac{d\lambda}{ds}$$
$$ \alpha '=\lambda '\times \dot \alpha\\
=\lambda ' \dot \alpha$$

Consequently,
$$\nabla_{\alpha'}{\alpha'}=\nabla_{\lambda ' \dot \alpha}{\lambda ' \dot \alpha}\\
=\lambda ' \nabla_{\dot \alpha}{\lambda ' \dot \alpha}\\
$$

Now, you can apply the Leibnitz rule and use $\nabla_\dot{\alpha}\dot{\alpha}=0$. It should be
$$=\lambda ' \nabla_{\dot \alpha}{\lambda ' \dot \alpha}\\
=\lambda ' {\dot \alpha}({\lambda ' )\dot \alpha}+\lambda ' \lambda '\nabla_{\dot \alpha}{ \dot \alpha}\\
=\lambda ' {\dot \alpha}({\lambda ' )\dot \alpha}+0$$

Comment: How/To what do I apply the Leibnitz rule when everything in your last paragraph equals to 0?

Comment: The Leibnitz rule should be applied to a term which is not in an equation, right?

Comment: Well done! I'll just check it now. Thanks.

Comment: Is the last equation equal to $(\lambda^{'})^2(\dot{\alpha})^2$? Why?

Comment: What is the relationship of $f$ in my OP and $\lambda '$?To use the Leibnitz rule, we need that $\lambda '$ and $f$ are both from $M$ to $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: But your $\lambda '$ goes from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$ while $f$ goes from $M$ to $\mathbb{R}$! Your $\lambda '$ is $\frac{d\lambda}{ds}$.

Comment: So could you rewrite your conclusion $$=\lambda ' {\dot \alpha}({\lambda ' )\dot \alpha}+0$$ using these inverses? Once $\lambda '$ is an argument, some other time it is a multiplicative constant and yet another time it is a function, so I'm confused...

Comment: But we usually evaluate it as $$\dot \alpha (f)=\frac{d}{dt}(f(\alpha))$$

Comment: Could you please still be more detailed? Could you rewrite this $$\lambda ' {\dot \alpha}({\lambda ' )\dot \alpha}+0$$ in terms of $f$ with together with directions like saying $f:M\to \mathbb{R}$ and $\alpha:\mathbb{R}\to M$?And similarly for $\lambda '$?

Comment: I now understand the source of my problems: your $f$ is from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$ while by the book of our local university professor it is from $M$! The things depend very much of what do we covariantly derive....